# Help with plant identification

Tags: identification, houseplants

I got this houseplant from my daughter, she called it a vining oak. Very distinct leaves, vines, no blooms yet except for clusters at the end of the vines.[image]

Comment: That is a very cool plant, where in the world is it growing?

Comment: Growing indoors in ND